# Does this limit exist (ln)?

Tags: calculus, limits

Does this limit exist and is finite?
(It goes to one from the left

$\lim_{x\to 1^-}{{(\ln(x) \times \ln(ln(x))}})$

I'm not sure about what the $\lim_{x\to 1^-}{{(\ln(ln(x))}})$ returns here. What do I do in this case?

Comment: Since you tagged the question [tag:calculus], I guess that $\ln$ is only defined for $x > 0$. But if $0 < x < 1$ then $\ln x < 0$, so $\ln (\ln x)$ is not defined.

Comment: you have to specify what you mean by a logarithm of negaive number...are you sure the limit isn't from the right?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. I guess it is a trick quesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(\ln(x))$ is only defined for $x>1$, because if $x<1$, then $\ln(x)<0$ which means that $\ln(\ln(x))$ is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

As noted by others if $x \to 1^{-}$ then the expression $\log\log x$ is not real and hence the limit does not exist as far as we are dealing with real functions of a real variable. On the other hand if $x \to 1^{+}$ then putting $t = \log x$ we see that $t \to 0^{+}$ and then $\log x \cdot \log \log x = t\log t \to 0$.

Comment: Yet another instance of anonymous downvote. Thanks to the downvoter for this wonderful gesture!